# Create a Private Remote Ivy Repository

Tags: repository, gradle, ivy

I've been doing quite a bit of searching and am unable to put all the pieces together.  I want to create an ivy repository on one of our servers.  I want to lock it down so it is private, and then be able to publish to this repository from Gradle.

I know how to publish using Gradle, and I have that working with a local ivy file system that Gradle creates:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  ivy {
    name "localRepos"
    url "${System.properties['user.home']}/repos"
  }
}

uploadArchives {
  repositories {
    add project.repositories.localRepos
  }
}
```

So what I need to do now is translate that into publishing to a remote private repos.  But first, obviously, I need to create that repos and I can't seem to figure that out from the Ivy documentation or Google searching.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

I'd prefer not to have to go down the Nexus, etc approach (no Maven).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Ivy repository is just a file store, and hence you need to set up a server (e.g. Apache httpd) that allows to read and write those files (e.g. via HTTP GET/PUT). However, I strongly recommend to use a repository manager. [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) is a good choice.

Comment: I second this proposal. Why reinvent the wheel? Artifactory and [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) are both free and fairly easy to setup. They both work with Ivy, Gradle, and even Maven.

Comment: Although Nexus has some support for Gradle, it is limited to Maven layout only, which is unnatural for Gradle. Artifactory, on the other hand, [fully supports native Gradle layout](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts#RepositoryLayouts-BundledLayouts).